# Copy all columns from one table to another table BUT few columns need to be specified php variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to copy columns from one table to another which is not the problem when I want to copy "AllInOne".

I will write:

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE condition;
```

If I need to copy only part of the columns I will write:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...) 
   SELECT column1, column2, column3, ... FROM table1 WHERE condition;
```

BUT

What if I need to copy all columns, but I need two or three columns with specified PHP variables that I am getting from `$_POST[]` or `$_GET[]`?
If I will have in the table only maybe ten columns together I will write it "manually" which is my second example. But I have more than 30 columns in my tables.... 
Therefore I am trying to find some combination where I can `INSERT *` and also specify `column2`, `column3` for example.

Is there some way how to do that? Something like this:

```
NSERT INTO table2 ( *, Price, Customer) SELECT ( *, '451', 'John') 
   FROM table1 WHERE condition;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  Just don't use the parentheses:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, . . ., price, customer)  -- list all columns here
    SELECT t1.*,  -- I advise you to list the columns here too
           451, 'John'
    FROM table1 t1
    WHERE condition;
```

Comment: THX Gordon but I am little confused :( what exactly is that t1.* also you are caling it again after table1. I have wrote something like this but ofcourse it doesn't help. INSERT INTO Invoice (Price, Customer) 
 SELECT t1.*,'451', 'John' FROM OldInvoice t1 WHERE Status = 'Active'; But mysql wrote alert: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: @daniel . . . `t1` is a table alias, so `t1.*` refers to all columns in the table, in the order they are defined.

Comment: I have tried every combination with your code but I am still getting sql error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*, Price, Customer SELECT OldInvoice.*,451, John FROM OldInvoice' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore I am trying to find some combination where I can INSERT * and also specify column2, column3 for example

This is really more of a SQL question then, if I'm not mistaking something? If your question is about binding variables in PHP then that's a different story, but it seems from your question that you know how to do that already.

SQL doesn't support a syntax that's like, "* for all the columns except for these columns." You'll just have to list out every column in the query. Using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT *` won't work for what you want to do, and is considered bad practice anyway (for example, if you drop or add a column from the table later, the query to select one into the other will break).

> If I will have in the table only maybe ten columns together I will write it "manually" which is my second example. But I have more than 30 columns in my tables...

Is that really so bad though? It's a small investment for code that works :)